# Pharo4 Spec GUI: How to change font size

Tags: smalltalk, specifications, pharo

I am thinking of programming my next project in Pharo. For this I will need to create a status monitor that can be seen from further away. The GUI is very simple. Basically just a few labels and buttons. Here is the problem: I need the font to be rather big - so that it can be seen from further away. How can I achieve this? Here is some sample code. My two labels need their font sitze changed:

```
initializeWidgets
  last1 := self newLabel.
  last1 label: '88,88'.

  last2 := self newLabel.
  last2 label: '99,99'.
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not well supported for now. You can workaround this problem be resetting
the font when the widget is built:

```
|lm|
lm:=LabelModel new.
lm label:'Hello'.
lm whenBuiltDo: [ :w | w widget font: (LogicalFont familyName: 'Source Code Pro' pointSize: 30)].
lm openWithSpec.
```

Comment: We are getting there - thanks! Only issue is that `self newLabel` will return a MorphicLabelAdapter. By the way so will `LabelModel new.` when used in my `initializeWidgets` method. And that doesn't understand `font:`. Any idea?

Comment: @NicolaiHess shouldn't we just introduce `font:` directly to LabelModel?

Comment: I would agree. Labels in particular, but also many other widgets will often need their font altered. Pretty standard for GUIs

Comment: If you're wondering how to do that, I've just added font support to PluggableButtonMorph and ButtonModel (slice 17707 in the Pharo50inbox)

Comment: Good find. Has this been fixed for Pharo 7.0?

Answer (score 0):

When using `lm whenBuiltDo:`within the `initializeWidgets`method of a ComposableModel we do not get the LabelModel as in above suggestion, but a MorphicLabelAdapter. That one does understand widget again and returns the LabelModel. So above example needs to read:

`...
lm whenBuiltDo: [ :w | w widget widget font: (LogicalFont familyName: 'Source Code Pro' pointSize: 30)].
lm openWithSpec.`

Comment: Oh, I think this is a bug.